# In what cases does a @comment reach a user?

Tags: support, comments, notifications

#### Background

- An edit on one of my posts was suggested. I reviewed and rejected it.
- I looked up the user and saw similar minor (approved) edits
- I @commented the user to ask him/her to do more substantial edits

#### Question

But I am not sure if a @comment will reach the user.

What if there are multiple users with the same displayname? How does the system know whom sending the comment? So the question is:

What participation in a post leads to a @notification?

- The user must be the poster or
- a commentor
- a previous editors?
- a (rejected) reviewer?
- a closer?
- a deleter?
- ...
- doesn't matter? All with the same name get the notification?

Comment: *You can explicitly notify one (1) other commenter, editor, or ♦ moderator who closed a question*

Comment: And *Matching is performed in reverse chronological order, so if five people named John are participating, @john will match the most recent John.*

Comment: And to be explicit: reviewers, the submitter of a rejected suggested edit, close voters (other than diamond moderators) and delete voters are *not* included in the list of people you can notify.